# jQuery not working after deployment to Site5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.8.7

I successfully deployed my app to Site5 - and as I started to play around on it, I realized that not all of the jQuery was working.  Specifically, anything that involved grabbing information from Ruby Forms.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) 
ut.extend.globalEval 
ut.fn.extend.domManip 
ut.fn.extend.replaceWith 
(anonymous function) 
ut.event.dispatch 
y.handle
```

The script is as followed, and worked locally, on heroku, and on hostmonster so I'm confused as to why it is not working now.
In the document:

```
<%= form_for :team_design, :url => {:controller => "team_designs", :action => 'create'} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :style %>   <%= f.select :style, [["Mens", "Mens"], ["Womens", "Womens"]], :include_blank=>'Select Style' %>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#target_div select#team_design_style').live('change', function () {
        var suitStyle = $(this).val();
        switch (suitStyle) {
                   //all the different case possibilities
    });
});
```

In Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

In my layout file

```
<head>
  <title>scrubbed</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

In my Gemfile, under assets

```
group :assets do
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'johnson'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Under Sources in Google Chrome:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2013-2-4
 */
 * Sizzle CSS Selector Engine
 * Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 */
* http://jqueryui.com
* Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.mouse.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js, jquery.ui.droppable.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js, jquery.ui.selectable.js, jquery.ui.sortable.js, jquery.ui.effect.js, jquery.ui.accordion.js, jquery.ui.autocomplete.js, jquery.ui.button.js, jquery.ui.datepicker.js, jquery.ui.dialog.js, jquery.ui.effect-blind.js, jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js, jquery.ui.effect-clip.js, jquery.ui.effect-drop.js, jquery.ui.effect-explode.js, jquery.ui.effect-fade.js, jquery.ui.effect-fold.js, jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js, jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js, jquery.ui.effect-scale.js, jquery.ui.effect-shake.js, jquery.ui.effect-slide.js, jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js, jquery.ui.menu.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.progressbar.js, jquery.ui.slider.js, jquery.ui.spinner.js, jquery.ui.tabs.js, jquery.ui.tooltip.js
* Copyright 2012 jQuery Foundation and other contributors; Licensed MIT */
```

Comment: You need to post all of the markup. If it's a lot, put it in a pastebin.

Comment: What version of jQuery are using and where do you get it from?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using v. 1.9.1 from jQuery.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> **.live( events, handler(eventObject) )** *Returns: jQuery*
>   version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9
>   [...]
>   **As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

So `live` was deprecated way back in version 1.7 (November 2011) and removed completely in 1.9. You're using jQuery 1.9.1 so there is no more `live`. Since you say that it worked in some places but not others then you must be mixing jQuery versions, that's just a shortcut to pain and suffering so don't mix versions.

Update your jQuery code to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` and `delegate`. The [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) documentation show you how to convert `live` and `delegate` to `on`.

You should start paying attention to release notes and update your code: don't wait until features are removed, update your code as soon as anything is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

- the gem jquery-rails is included in your assets group in your gemfile
- jquery is included in your javascript manifest file
- you compiled assets during deployment

Comment: the jquery-rails gem was not included under assets - I tried moving it there running bundle instal and precompiling the assets but that didnt change anything.  In my application.js I do have all the //= require statements, and I precompile the assets using rake assets:precompile.  I believe that satisfies those, if not let me know